# White space between images when using Masonry with imagesLoaded

Tags: jquery, html, css, whitespace, masonry

I'm having a bit of trouble when using Masonry with imagesLoaded that spacing between images, it will be disappeard if I zoom window size. Hope anyone can give me solution for my issue.

http://jsfiddle.net/7hs958sr/embedded/result/

[image]

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="grid-sizer"></div>
    <div class="item height2">
        <img src="http://thumbnails111.imagebam.com/34789/32a0b0347888848.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <img src="http://thumbnails111.imagebam.com/34789/c17f67347888951.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <img src="http://thumbnails111.imagebam.com/34789/c17f67347888951.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <img src="http://thumbnails111.imagebam.com/34789/c17f67347888951.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <img src="http://thumbnails111.imagebam.com/34789/c17f67347888951.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <img src="http://thumbnails111.imagebam.com/34789/c17f67347888951.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="item height2">
        <img src="http://thumbnails111.imagebam.com/34789/32a0b0347888848.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <img src="http://thumbnails111.imagebam.com/34789/c17f67347888951.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <img src="http://thumbnails111.imagebam.com/34789/c17f67347888951.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <img src="http://thumbnails111.imagebam.com/34789/c17f67347888951.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
</div>
<!-- end container -->
```

**CSS**

```
.grid-sizer, .item{
    width: 25%;
}

.item{
    float: left;
    height: 295px;
}

img{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.height2{
    height: 590px;
}
```

**JS**

```js
var $container = $('#container');

$container.imagesLoaded(function () {
    $container.masonry({
        columnWidth: '.grid-sizer',
        itemSelector: '.item'
    });
});
```

Comment: Your jsfiddle example shows no sign of this problem..

Comment: I'm using Firefox and I still getting it.